# Immediate Disconnection from Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, users

When I attempt to connect to my remote server, the response I get:

> This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator.

is very, very immediate. In addition, the remote computer is online, and I'm also the only one with access. I'm connected one moment, then it gives me this disconnection notice, and attempting post-disconnection results in this message popping up almost immediately after initiating the session. Has anyone else encountered this phenomenon? I can jump on the website the server hosts just fine.

Just so we don't have any issues with this, I don't think solutions for the general "disconnection" problem would be very helpful. This is a very specific issue that does not relate to the usual problem of networking issues, etc.

Comment: I future please denote a question with a question mark, please don't imply a question. The rdp service is refusing connections restart the service and re-connect

Comment: On which end? How do you expect me to restart the service when I'm miles away from the server?

Comment: To question 1 server end to question 2 remotely

Comment: How do you solve that error when you can't even connect?

Comment: Eventually, it connects, but while it's having this error, you can't get in or out.

Comment: Please see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759202.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187836/how-do-i-restart-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-in-windows

Comment: Can you ping the remote server?

Comment: Try the steps listed in this article to see if it resolves the problem for you. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2477176